# make a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have a function in php that is used to draw a tree menu and i want to make same function but in javascript to do the same .. but im new in java script  so i need help

This is the Function in javascript

```
/**
* Recursive Function to show the nested Menu 
* @param $data array of all the data in DataBase
* @param $level choose the level form which the nested menu will start 
* @return nested menu in Html Form.
*/
function recursive($data, $level) {
   $r = "<ul>";
   foreach ( $data as $i ) {

       if ($i['parent'] == $level ) {
          $r = $r . "<li><a href='#' onclick = 'getId(".$i['id'].")'>" . $i['title'] . recursive( $data, $i['id'] ) . "</a></li>";
       }
   }
   $r = $r . "</ul>";
   return $r;
}
```

Where the data parameter is the data from database and it come in the

```
    array (size=11)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '44' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'shreif' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '50' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '44' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'ssss' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '53' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '50' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'asdddd' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '54' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '53' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '55' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '54' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'sad' (length=3)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '62' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '44' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '63' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '62' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'dddd' (length=4)
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '64' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '63' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'sad' (length=3)
  8 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '67' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '64' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'asd' (length=3)
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '68' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '0' (length=1)
      'title' => string 'aaaa' (length=4)
  10 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '69' (length=2)
      'parent' => string '67' (length=2)
      'title' => string 'asd' (length=3)
```

and level parameter is level to begin with i use O to print me a tree like this

```
> shreif
       ssss
         asdddd
           asd
             sad
       asd
         dddd
           sad
             asd
              asd
 aaaa
```

i take that data and changed it to json like this :

```
var old_data = '<?php echo json_encode($nested); ?>';
```

and i get this

```
[
{"id":"44","parent":"0","title":"shreif"},
{"id":"50","parent":"44","title":"ssss"},
{"id":"53","parent":"50","title":"asdddd"},
{"id":"54","parent":"53","title":"asd"},
{"id":"55","parent":"54","title":"sad"},
{"id":"62","parent":"44","title":"asd"},
{"id":"63","parent":"62","title":"dddd"},
{"id":"64","parent":"63","title":"sad"},
{"id":"67","parent":"64","title":"asd"},
{"id":"68","parent":"0","title":"aaaa"},
{"id":"69","parent":"67","title":"asd"}];
```

so i need a function to take this and draw the same nested menu like i did in php any help

and this is my Try :

```
function recursive(data,level)
{
    var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
    for ( i in data )
    {
        if ( i['parent'] == level ) 
        {
           var r = item.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
                "<li><a href='#' onclick = 'getId(".i['id'].")'>" . i['title'] . recursive( data, i['id'] ) . "</a></li>")
            );
        }

    }
    list.appendChild(r);
}
```

is it Right ?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (We're not here to do all the work - you need to have at least attempted to solve this yourself after reading the relevant documentation.)

Comment: Dear @Shreif A., This site is not to teach you the code but to help you in your code. So plz learn javaScript and try something first. We will help you if you have any difficulty in the code. use the link: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=javascript+tutorial&oq=javascript&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j69i61l2j69i60j0l2.6282j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @adrinao thanks .. and sorry for posting this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your select list with an id. Like this:

```
<ul id="mylist"> </ul>
```

Then you can find it and add to it with this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("mylist");
var item = document.createElement('li');
item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("WHATEVER YOU WANT"));
list.appendChild(item);
```

Throw all of this inside a loop and you've got your function.

Comment: Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kuLwv/5/

Comment: can u see my edit and tell me is it right ?!

Comment: It looks correct. It would need tested to be sure. Also, it's a little misleading to call the function recursive since there is no recursion going on within it. Maybe name it something more appropriate :) Good Luck!